# Regular expression convert Date format from dd-mon-yy to dd/MM/yy

Tags: regex, powershell

Wondering, is that a regex in powershell can replace date from dd-mon-yy to dd/MM/yy

Example: 25-FEB-16 change to 25/02/16

Comment: Not saying it can't be done (although I can't see a way right away without perl eval regex syntax), but it sure won't be a pretty regex. I'd think there are better ways to write that replacement.

Comment: Please use date functions imo.

Comment: There is no regex for what you want to do, because regex can't translate "FEB" to "02". Regex is the wrong approach.

Comment: What tool are you using? I fear that you need 12 replacement like "-JAN-" to "/01/" and so on. Twelve simple replacements (not regex replacements) should be enough. If you are using a programming language you could put the strings inside arrays.

Comment: I'm using powershell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[DateTime]::ParseExact()` as regex would require 12 different replace-operations, or a `MatchEvalutor` to convert the month.

Example using regex `MatchEvaluator`:

```
$MatchEvaluator = {  
  param($match) 

  #Could have used a switch-statement too..
  $month = [datetime]::ParseExact($match.Groups[2].Value,"MMM",$null).Month

  "{0:00}/{1:00}/{2:00}" -f $match.Groups[1].Value, $month, $match.Groups[3].Value
}

[regex]::Replace("25-FEB-16","(\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+)", $MatchEvaluator)
25/02/16
```

Looking at that, I would say that using only `ParseExact()` is a much better solution:

```
try {
    [datetime]::ParseExact("25-FEB-16","dd-MMM-yy", $null).ToString("dd/MM/yy", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
} catch {
    #Invalid date-format
}
25/02/16
```

Comment: Not sure why you put the backslashes in front of the slashes in your format string?

Comment: `/` is a date delimiter, so it will output the delimiter for the culture, which for me ended up with `25.02.16`. Using `InvariantCulture` will fix it too.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution here would be to use the date parsing and formatting functions rather than regex-based string replacement.

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('25-FEB-16', 'dd-MMM-yy', $null).ToString('dd/MM/yy', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
# => 25/02/16
```

This also gets you built-in locale sensitivity in case you run on a system where the dates come in with the month names in another language. But using `ParseExact` and the `InvariantCulture` option means that the locale-sensitivity won't mess with your specified formats.